# Failed to reinstall Android APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I had a small problem with my Android application. I wanted to change the name of the project because I had two of the same name I suppressed one and removed the figure '2' from the one I chose to keep. Now that I want to run it, it shows me an error message. Already two days that I am trying to solve is problem but I am really very very beginner especially on Android.

[image]

Comment: Can you put the error message here?

Comment: in which device you run APK.

Comment: This is not the problem. Whenever you run the application in your device and change then after you change the version it will give you this message.Don't worry you can press OK it will reinstall the app again.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the project has no effect on it. What you have to do is to chage the application id in the build.gradle file

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I am a beginner, it is not obvious to see or go to change this problem, you can make me a screenshot so I can see the steps to follow to get rid of, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**There are many possibilities to show this message.**

> 1) If you run the application which is already installed in your
>   device and then you change application id.
>
> 2) If you install the Signed APK which is already in your device and
>   you try to run the APK which is debug APK that time this dialog show.
>
> 3) You uninstall the application using drag and drop and you think
>   application is uninstalled but in many devices which run with dual
>   account will not remove the apps and it shows in app management but it
>   is not showing in the apps list. In that case when you run the
>   application you show this message.
>
> To solve 3rd issue manually go to app settings and uninstall the app
>   otherwise it won't allow you to install the application.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I am a beginner, it is not obvious to see or go to change this problem, you can make me a screenshot so I can see the steps to follow to get rid of, thank you in advance